# Showing that $A \otimes_B A \to A$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let us define a homomorphism $\phi: A \otimes_B A \to A$ by $a \otimes a' \to aa'$ where $A$ is a $B$-algebra, and both $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings.

I want to show that this is a surjective homomorphism. Unfortunately, I am struggling with some tensor arithmetic.

In particular, how do I simplify $x \otimes x' + y \otimes y'$ where both $x,y \in A$ ? I think I would need some simplification to show that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: If you mean $x\otimes x' + y \otimes y'$, there is no reason to believe that a simplification exists (the sum of simple tensors need not be a simple tensor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is surjective because $\phi(1\otimes a) =a$ so every $a\in A$ is in the image.

To show that it's a $B$-algebra morphism, first you must show that it's a well-defined $B$-module morphism : this follows from the universal property of tensor products, since $A\times A\to A$ defined by $(a,a')\mapsto aa'$ is $B$-bilinear.

Then to check that $\phi(xy)= \phi(x)\phi(y)$, it suffices to show it for pure tensors (since then it will follow by bilinearity for general tensors). But $$\phi((a\otimes a')(b\otimes b')) = \phi(ab\otimes a'b') = aba'b'=aa'bb' = \phi(a\otimes a')\phi(b\otimes b').$$

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I am still having a hard time showing it a ring homomorphism.

Comment: It's not a ring morphism unless $A$ is commutative.

Comment: Sorry! I should have added that.

Comment: I edited to be more precise.

Comment: Do I not need to show that $\phi(x +y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$ ?

Comment: This follows from the universal property. Otherwise your application would not even be defined (you only provide a formula for pure tensors).

Comment: Ok. So I know there is a unique $B$-linear mapping $\phi: A \otimes_B A \to A$ if we view $A \otimes_B A$ and $A$ as $B$-modules. So the ring homomorphism conditions are already satisfied via the universal property.

Comment: Well at least the $B$-module conditions. There is a stronger universal property for $B$-algebras that basically says that the tensor product is the coproduct in the category of commutative $B$-algebras, but given your question I assumed you were not familiar with it.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.